# matrix equality proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

suppose I vectors $x_1,\dots,x_n$ span $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let's define

$$N^{-1} = \sum_i \lambda_i x_ix_i^T$$

for scalars $\lambda_i\ge 0$. Now why does the following equality hold?

$$\sum_i\lambda_i(x_i^TNx_i-1) =-\sum_i\lambda_i + n$$

This is

Comment: I bet there's a plus instead of that minus

Comment: Are the $x_i$ orthonormal?

Comment: Let $X$ denote the matrix with columns $x_1,\dots,x_n$, and let $\Lambda$ denote the  diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$. The matrix $N$ is given by $N = [X \Lambda X^T]^{-1} = X^{-T} \Lambda^{-1} X^{-1}$. The left hand side of the sum is given by
$$
\operatorname{Tr}(X^T\Lambda^{1/2}N\Lambda^{1/2}X - \Lambda). 
$$
I don't see any reason that this should simplify nicely in general

Comment: @Exodd your spot on!

Comment: @BenGrossmann its motivated from the exercise in Boyd,[link](http://egrcc.github.io/docs/math/cvxbook-solutions.pdf) page 224. In their notation $Q=N$ and $a_i=x_i$

Comment: @swissy Can you point to exactly where in the solution you believe this equation is/should be used?

Comment: @BenGrossmann there is an easy way to simplify it without using the trace. Notice that $x_i = Xe_i$

Comment: @Exodd Why would a sum over all $i$ be simpler than using the trace?

Comment: @BenGrossmann because $x_i^TNx_i = 1/\lambda_i$...

Comment: @Exodd That's a good reason

Comment: @Exodd It's also needlessly complicated because I had the $\Lambda^{1/2}$ on the wrong side of the $X$'s. Otherwise, I could have used the cyclic property of the trace as user1551 did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of matrices, the given condition is $N^{-1}=X\Lambda X^T$ while the equality in question is $\operatorname{tr}\left(\Lambda(X^TNX-I)\right)=n-\operatorname{tr}(\Lambda)$. It can be proved by using the tracial property $\operatorname{tr}(XY)=\operatorname{tr}(YX)$:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}\left(\Lambda(X^TNX-I)\right)
&=\operatorname{tr}(\Lambda X^TNX)-\operatorname{tr}(\Lambda)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(X\Lambda X^TN)-\operatorname{tr}(\Lambda)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(N^{-1}N)-\operatorname{tr}(\Lambda)\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(I_n)-\operatorname{tr}(\Lambda)\\
&=n-\operatorname{tr}(\Lambda).\\
\end{align}